# ADO.NET, SQL Server, C#: how to check if a certain parameter does not exist before performing an Insert in a database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, ado.net

I'm still learning ADO.NET database programming and I would classify myself as a beginner. I created a method `AddReview` that adds a Review for specific movie to a table `dbo.Reviews`. The columns in `dbo.Reviews` include `VideoID`, `UserID`, and the review text.

The method requires to throw an exception if the `VideoID` and `UserID` do not exist. There is table `dbo.Videos` that contains the `VideoID` and another table `dbo.User` that contains the `UserID`. The code I provided below does the insert but does not check whether the `VideoID` and `UserID` exist before doing the insert.

How would I write a T-SQL command to check for this? If `UserID` or `VideoID` does not exist, throw an exception, otherwise continue with the insert.

Thanks in advance.

```
public void AddReview(int videoId, Guid userId, string reviewText)
{
    var connSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VideoLibrary"];
    var connString = connSettings.ConnectionString;

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO dbo.Reviews (VideoId, UserId, Review)
                            VALUES (@VideoID, @UserID, @Review)";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("VideoID", videoId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserID", userId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Review", reviewText);

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create foreign keys in dbo.Reviews table to make sure you can insert only valid values.

For example,

```
ALTER TABLE Reviews
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_VideoID
FOREIGN KEY (VideoID) REFERENCES dbo.Videos(VideoID);

ALTER TABLE Reviews
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_UserID
FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES dbo.Users(UserID);
```

Unless you make a call to database (affects performance) to check if VideoID and UserID exists before inserting, there is no other way. You do not have to worry about inserting invalid values if you have your foreign keys setup.